# Написание своего класса Lock

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня задача написать свой механизм блокировок `Lock`. И я нашел уже готовый самописный пример, упрощенной версии этого механизма:

```
public class Lock {

    boolean isLocked = false;
    Thread  lockedBy = null;
    int     lockedCount = 0;

public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException{
      Thread callingThread = Thread.currentThread();
      while(isLocked && lockedBy != callingThread){
          wait();
      }
      isLocked = true;
      lockedCount++;
      lockedBy = callingThread;
  }


  public synchronized void unlock(){
      if(Thread.curentThread() == this.lockedBy) {
          lockedCount--;

            if(lockedCount == 0){
               isLocked = false;
               notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И меня ставят в ступор здесь несколько вещей:

**1**. Зачем нужен счетчик `lockedCount` какую проблему он решает?

**2**. Зачем нужен Thread `callingThread = Thread.currentThread();`? В чем идея этой проверки: `lockedBy != callingThread`? Какую проблему он решает?

Почему не сделать вот так, и успокоится:

```
public class Lock {

    private boolean isLocked = false;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        while(isLocked) {
            wait();
        }
        isLocked = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock(){
        isLocked = false;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Зачем нужны эти дополнительные проверки что за проблему они решают?

Comment: Никто тут не решает никакую проблему, простой велосипед.

Comment: попробуй готовые решения из `java.util.concurent` https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/157273/ - тут об этой библиотеке хорошо рассказывают

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Зачем нужен счетчик lockedCount какую проблему он решает?

Он позволяет потоку-владельцу блокировки блокировать ресурс многократно.

> 2. Зачем нужен Thread callingThread = Thread.currentThread();? В чем идея этой проверки: lockedBy != callingThread? Какую проблему он решает?

Для возможности сравнить текущий поток с тем, что владеет lock в данный момент.

> Почему не сделать вот так, и успокоит**ь**ся

Сделайте, не проблема. Вот только что делать, если текущий поток вызовет lock() повторно?

Comment: а что мешает без счетчика использовать ресурс многократно? есть же `isLocked` он при вызове `unlock()` переключится в `false` и можно опять использовать... А счетчик тут при чем?

Comment: Имеется в виду "многократно, без unlock"... Проблема возникает при повторном вызове lock(), без unlock.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что один и тот же поток вызовет `lock()` дважды, не освободив при этом ресурс после первого захвата. Если поток вызовет дважды `lock()`, не вызвав после первого `unlock()`, то мы получим Deadlock на одном потоке.

Comment: Не вижу в ответе слова "рекурсия" :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
public synchronized void unlock(){
  if(Thread.curentThread() == this.lockedBy) {
      lockedCount--;

        if(lockedCount == 0){
           isLocked = false;
           notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Этот метод можно поломать, если вызвать unlook без надобности - count может уйти меньше нуля и блокировка не снимется в дальнейшем. Тут надо либо добавить сбросы на null lockedBy или поправить проверку счётчика + его сброс.

Comment: Вызов unlook без надобности ломает что угодно, и простыми проверками тут что-то сделать трудно. Разве что спрятать unlock за AutoCloseable-токеном, который бы отслеживал повторные закрытия...

Comment: Это вы как программист думаете, а не как юзер